# How can enter list of names that change in every page

Tags: conditionals

I have  list of names :

1. Jhon Doe
2. name 2
3. ...

   and I want to put them in top left  corner.

How to put these names in order on each page automatically. background package or eso-pic tikz with fancyhdr ?

page1 Jhon Doe

page2  name2

...

...

...

Any advice ?

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{name 1} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to define the names as such with the `etoolbox` pacakge.

```
\csdef{Name 1}{John Doe}
\csdef{Name 2}{Mr Anderson}
\csdef{Name 3}{Han Solo}
\csdef{Name 4}{Steve Jobs}
\csdef{Name 5}{Yoda}
\csdef{Name 6}{Joe Smith}
```

Then, using

```
\fancyhead[L]{\csuse{Name \thepage}}
```

you obtain the desired results:

[image]

### Note:

- The code below was modified with

  ```
    \usepackage[paperheight=11cm, paperwidth=8cm]{geometry}
  ```

  to produce the image.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\csuse{Name \thepage}} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\csdef{Name 1}{John Doe}%
\csdef{Name 2}{Mr Anderson}%
\csdef{Name 3}{Han Solo}%
\csdef{Name 4}{Steve Jobs}%
\csdef{Name 5}{Yoda}%
\csdef{Name 6}{Joe Smith}%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !